# Page transitions on websites?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was just wondering if there are any methods of creating nice, smooth transition effects when navigating between pages? Things like blind effects, sliding effects, etc. I guess I'm looking for something like what jQuery can do with images - but for actual web pages. I know there are fade effects and all that, but I was just wondering if there was something more 'modern' out there. While I realize Flash would be a good fit for this, it is not an option.

Comment: Do people really like cheesy effects in page transitions?

Comment: No, I do not believe so.

Comment: I sure don't. This was the request of a client. I was hoping to take the easy way out and dissuade him by saying its not possible; if not I could just show how cheesy and browser specific the javascript effects are that I *did* find.

Comment: Well, I guess I didn't really help your 'not possible' case so much but it seems that I probably helped out on the cheesy part... Good luck convincing him otherwise--some people are just so stubborn. :-/

Comment: this is definitely doable but you might be able to talk them out of it on the negative usability aspect of it - people hate to wait and a full page transition is totally frivolous and would definitely annoy users.  Ask them if they have ever seen a major successful website that has such a behavior - not going to find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do some pretty cool effects if you use jQuery UI. They will go much smoother if you load everything in using AJAX... but, here's an example to get it working with full page loads.

First you need to additionally include jQuery UI (I just [built my own](http://jqueryui.com/download) and only grabbed the effects I needed):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js"></script>
```

And here's the javascript you'll need to make it work.

```
$(function() {
    $('body').hide();
    $('a').bind('click', function() { 
        var newPage = $(this).attr('href');
        $('body').hide('blind',{},500, function() {
            newPageParts =  newPage.split('?');
            newPageURL = newPageParts[0];
            newPageParams = newPageParts[1];
            newPage = newPageURL+"?transition=true"+(newPageParams != undefined ? "&"+newPageParams : '');
            window.location=newPage;
        });
        return false;
    });
    if(getURLParam('transition') != '') {
        $('body').show('blind',{},500,null);
    }
});

function getURLParam(strParamName){
    var strReturn = "";
    var strHref = window.location.href;
    if ( strHref.indexOf("?") > -1 ){
        var strQueryString = strHref.substr(strHref.indexOf("?")).toLowerCase();
        var aQueryString = strQueryString.split("&");
        for ( var iParam = 0; iParam < aQueryString.length; iParam++ ){
            if (aQueryString[iParam].indexOf(strParamName + "=") > -1 ){
                var aParam = aQueryString[iParam].split("=");
                strReturn = aParam[1];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return strReturn;
}
```

Of course, fading in is only going to work on pages that have this script on it...

**Just a note:** I did just kinda make this in a few minutes so it might be really ghetto. But, it does work... so... yeah...

Comment: This is so completely rad... /sarcasm

Answer (score 0):

IE has a very simple implementation of [page transition effects](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/iePageTransition/index.html), but I don't think they will work on other browsers like Mozilla and Safari.