# page transitions with jquery and php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm using php to develop an application, and I'm using something like this to change the pages

```
<?php
            if (!isset($_GET["p"])){
                $p = 'home';
            } else{
                $p = $_GET["p"];
            }
            include "$p.php";
?>
```

What I want to know is if there is a way to put some effects with JQuery when I change the page

Something like a loading icon or anything that makes the browser not to display that white page when going from a page to another, can you understand what I want?

At first I was using hidden `divs` and show/hide, but that usually made the JQuery effects 
within this `divs` get all messed up, so i changed to `php include`.

What I need is that people won't feel like leaving on page to reach another, I want them to feel like they're just changing the contents .

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781654/page-transitions-on-websites?rq=1

Comment: Consider using a "whitelist" of allowed pages. In case `allow_url_include` is enabled on your server this could be exploited to run malicious code on your server.

Comment: how do i rate the answers? '-'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just making a link to each page, I don't think its possible.

What you can do is make page change by ajax. Something like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>

$("#home").click(function() {
  $.ajax("index.php?p=home")
    .done(function(pageHtml) {
      $("#content").html(pageHtml);
    });
});
```

Where the link to home has `id="home"` and replace `$("#content").html(pageHtml);` with an effect.

Comment: thanks brother, this worked very well!! now i have to figure out how to replace with the effect xD

Comment: Great! For the effects use: http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/ or http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects. Please remember to accept an answer.

Comment: yeah, i know i have to accept, just don't know how xD

Comment: The tick below the down vote arrow.

Comment: oh, thanks, i also add a fade in effect, found this usefull topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183638/making-my-ajax-updated-div-fade-in, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

read about standard page transition effects here: http://www.boogiejack.com/transition_effects.html

Comment: i tried this, and its not working for me, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax to load the page and give that a effect using jquery. This can suit what you asked.

```
<script>
$("#home").click(function() {
  $.ajax("index.php?p=home").done(function(pageHtml) {
      $("#body").html();
    });
});
</script>
<body id="body">
  <a id="home">Home</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Ok be sure to accept the answer